# Symfony2 change doctrine generated mapping and entity location

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Symfony2 project I have one bundle called MyBundle\BlogBundle. I'm using the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyBundleBlogBundle xml
```

To generate mapping files in xml format. The default location in which the mapping files are generated is:

```
src/MyBundle/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine
```

I would like to change that. It would be very nice if that directory could be:

```
src/MyBundle/BlogBundle/Mapping
```

Is this even possible to do? Above all I would like to change my Entity directory to:

```
src/MyBundle/BlogBundle/Model
```

This also does not seems to work with the doctrine:mapping:import command. For this to change I tried stuff like changing the config.yml to:

```
    orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        MyBundle:
            mappings:
                MyBundleBlogBundle:
                    mapping: true
                    type: xml
                    dir: Model
                    alias: 'MyBundleBlogBundle'
                    prefix: 'MyBundle\BlogBundle\Model'
                    is_bundle: true
```

But this also does not seems to work. After this I did some research on Compiler Passes as used by e.g. the FosUserBundle. But I don't understand a lot of that yet.

Can I get the doctrine:mapping:import command to work with my desired directories? Or do I need to forget this command and create all the mappings and entities myself?

I would prefer to solve it with a Compiler Pass, but do not know how. Most important is the use of the Model directory instead of the Entity dir.

Comment: Do everything works after changing `dir` in config and moving files from `/Resources/config/doctrine` to `/Model` manually?

Comment: Problem is that the entity location in the xml files still points at the Entity directory instead of the configured (Model) directory.

Comment: Decided at last to just go with the default Symfony2 directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.  In my case, is_bundle is set to false but it should work pretty much the same.  As @user3749178 has suggested, your dir is probably wrong.  Tweak the locations as necessary.

```
doctrine:
entity_managers:

  games:
    connection: games
    mappings:
      foo1: 
        prefix: Cerad\Bundle\ProjectGameBundle\Doctrine\Entity\Foo1
        type:   yml
        dir:    "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/ProjectGameBundle/Doctrine/EntityMapping/Foo1"
        is_bundle: false
      foo2: 
        prefix: Cerad\Bundle\ProjectGameBundle\Doctrine\Entity\Foo2
        type:   yml
        dir:    "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/ProjectGameBundle/Doctrine/EntityMapping/Foo2"
        is_bundle: false
```

Update

Looks like I misunderstood the main point of the question.  Take a look at:

```
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/

namespace Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command

class ImportMappingDoctrineCommand extends DoctrineCommand
{
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $bundle = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getBundle($input->getArgument('bundle'));

    $destPath = $bundle->getPath();
    $type = $input->getArgument('mapping-type') ? $input->getArgument('mapping-type') : 'xml';
    if ('annotation' === $type) {
        $destPath .= '/Entity';
    } else {
        $destPath .= '/Resources/config/doctrine';
    }
```

As you can see, the mapping file directory is hard coded.  No way to adjust where the xml files will end up.  You will have to copy them over yourself and then edit the entity path.  It's a one shot deal.

Comment: Sure this works, But how can I get the doctrine:mapping:import command to point to the right directory MyBundle\BlogBundle\Model\ instead of MyBundle\BlogBundle\Entity

Comment: See my update.  You woud have to write your own command to change the folder.